# Order customers by the amount of invoices and sum of items

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to order my customers by the amount of invoices and the sum of the values of invoices. To get the value of a invoice, I need to sum the items, that can (or not) be in 2 tables: products and support. The structure is something like this:

[image]

I tried this query, but doesn't works:

```
SELECT 
    c.id, 
    c.name, 
    COUNT(i.id) as total_amount, 
    SUM(ip.value * ip.quantity) as total_products,
    SUM(sp.value) as total_support
FROM InVoice i
INNER JOIN Costumer c ON i.id_costumer = c.id
LEFT JOIN InVoice_Product ip ON ip.id_invoice = i.id
LEFT JOIN InVoice_Support sp ON sp.id_invoice = i.id
GROUP BY c.id, c.name
ORDER BY total_amount, total_products DESC
```

If I exec the query without the LEFT JOINS, only looking for the amount of invoices, works great.. But when I try to add the JOINS, the results doesn't match with reality..

I'm stucked on this.

**EDIT:**

Fiddle with expected result (total amount): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f001a7/4

Fiddle with complete query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f001a7/5

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: if you can share sql fiddle that be great

Comment: Sorry.. I edit the question and share fiddles with the results. The total_amount increases when the query have the JOINs and SUMs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must use a DISTINCT count, and also sum the sums of products and support.

```
SELECT 
    c.id, 
    c.name, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT i.id) as invoices_count, 
    SUM(ip.value * ip.quantity) + SUM(is.value) as total_amount
FROM Invoice i
INNER JOIN Costumer c ON i.id_costumer = c.id
LEFT JOIN InVoice_Product ip ON ip.id_invoice = i.id
LEFT JOIN InVoice_Support sp ON sp.id_invoice = i.id
GROUP BY c.id, c.name
ORDER BY invoices_count, total_amount DESC
```

Give it a try

Comment: Worked! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is doing math on values that may be null. Give this a try:

```
SELECT
    c.id, 
    c.name, 
    COUNT(i.id) as total_amount, 
    SUM(IF(NOT ip.value IS NULL,ip.value * ip.quantity,0)) as total_products,
    SUM(IF(NOT is.value IS NULL,is.value,0)) as total_support
FROM Invoice i
INNER JOIN Costumer c ON i.id_costumer = c.id
LEFT JOIN InVoice_Product ip ON ip.id_invoice = i.id
LEFT JOIN InVoice_Support sp ON sp.id_invoice = i.id
GROUP BY c.id, c.name
ORDER BY total_amount, total_products DESC
```

Comment: I tried.. total_support and total_products looks to be ok, but total_amount is not correct... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f001a7/14

Answer (score 0):

Just 'unioned' the two tables and invoice_product and invoice_support as current query finds invoice_id common in all three tables (invoice, invoice_product, invoice_support):

```
select c.id, c.name, count (inv_prod_support.id_invoice), sum(inv_prod_support*quantity) as total_products,
sum(inv_prod_support.value) as total_support from
(select id_invoice, value, 0 as quantity from invoice_support
union select id_invoice, value, quantity from invoice_product ) inv_prod_support, invoice i
inner join customer c on i.id_customer = c.id
inner join inv_prod_support on inv_prod_support.id_invoice = i.id_invoice
group by c.id, c.name
order by total_amount, total_products desc
```